# In contractual jobs in the software development space, do compensation increases happen annually or at the start of each contract renewal?

Tags: salary, contractors, contract-extension

If I was hired in January and my contract expires and will be renewed in July, should I expect a salary increase then or at the end of the year like everybody else?

Comment: Are you contracted through some kind of intermediary agency? or a consulting company?

Comment: intermediary agency

Answer (score 3):

In contract work your compensation is one of the terms and can only be (re)negotiated when your contract is (re)negotiated.

> should I expect a salary increase

No, you should not *expect* it; you can try to negotiate an increase when and if the contract renewal is offered to you.

Under the contract you are a vendor of services to the other party. Why would your client be expected to pay more for the same services just because some time interval has passed?

Comment: A contract can be renegotiated at any time though. The bargaining dynamic is a lot different if you're on the middle of a contract though.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't really understand the situation here, but you can't just terminate a contract if the other party asks if it can be renegotiated.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Of course, if the OP has a contract with an intermediary, that's who they should speak with. I'm not suggesting they are under any obligation to pay more at all. Renegotiating terms of a contract is not uncommon (though maybe it is in your industry).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Fair enough. But I'm not suggesting that the employee can renegotiate with the "deployment" side company. My point was that two parties can sit down and modify an existing contract (held between themselves).

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it when a new contract is being drawn up, if at all. And maybe it wouldn't even be when the first six month contract expires but maybe it'd be when the second six month contract expires (since that'd be a year later).

Ultimately, I think it'd probably depend on the reason why you were on a fixed month contract anyway. Like if your company was doing defense work and they, themselves, had received a six month contract from the US government to work on some project, then whether or not your contract would be renewed or include a pay increase would depend on if your employee had their contract renewed, budget increased or staffing requirements reduced.